# C# Linq query to return Dictionary<int,int[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary, int

Ok, so I have a need to create/return a Dictionary from the results of a Linq Query. I have tried just about everything I can think of and keep running into issues. Here is what I am currently attempting...

```
public static Dictionary<int,int[]> GetEntityAuthorizations(int userId)
    {
        using (MyDb db = new MyDb())
        {
            var query = db.EntityManagerRoleAssignments.Where(x => x.EntityManager.ManagerId == userId);
            var entityId = query.Select(x => x.EntityManager.EntityId);
            var roles = query.Select(x => x.RoleId).ToArray();
            var result = query.ToDictionary(entityId, roles);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

any help at all would be greatly appreciated. what i am looking for to be returned from this is a Dictionary where the Key is the entityId or EntityManager.EntityId and the Value(s) are an array of associated RoleId's.

Currently I am getting the following two errors at compile time, and other attempts have been errors similar but not exact to these.

> Error 11  The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>
> Error 12  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,Sqor.Database.DbEntityManagerRoleAssignment>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,int[]>'

**UPDATE - Working Solution (Thanks to @D Stanley)**

```
public static Dictionary<int,int[]> GetEntityAuthorizations(int userId)
    {
        using (SqorDb db = new SqorDb())
        {
            var query = db.EntityManagerRoleAssignments.Where(x => x.EntityManager.ManagerId == userId);
            var entityGroups = query.GroupBy(x => x.EntityManager.EntityId);
            var result = entityGroups.ToDictionary(e => e.Key,
                                                   g => g.Select(x => x.RoleId).ToArray()
                                                  );
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is it currently doing versus what you want it to do?

Comment: Why do you want a dictionary with a single pair? The method takes a single userid so this dictionary won't contain more than one keyvaluepair. Let it return a `int[]`.

Comment: your right, i've edited my code to better display what I'm after...

Comment: key will be entityId, sorry.

Comment: You're just trying to smash two enumerables together. You're probably looking for something in the line of `query.ToDictionary(x => x.EntityManager.EntityId, x => x.RoleId)`. But here `RoleId` is not an array.

Comment: Right, and I need it to be, but can't for the life of me figure out the right way to do so. Thanks everyone for the comments, you've already helped me see things I was doing wrong/overlooking cause I've been on this for days...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to group by the Entity ID and project the associated role IDs to an array:

```
using (MyDb db = new MyDb())
{
    var query = db.EntityManagerRoleAssignments.Where(x => x.EntityManager.ManagerId == userId);
    var entityGroups = query.GroupBy(x => x.EntityManager.EntityId);
    var result = entityGroups.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, 
                                           g => g.Select(x => x.RoleId).ToArray()
                                          );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Trying this. Thank you D Stanley.

Comment: I think this works perfect D Stanley, on first run it appeared it had 3 entries, the first one being correct, with the second two being 0,0. However, after the code block was finished, GetEntityAuthorizations only had one set, which would be correct.

Comment: Glad it worked.  Debugging Linq queries by inspecting them can be tricky.  Usually you need to look at the final results rather then trying to inspect intermediate results.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and I was having a super hard time getting anything semi-correct to see a final result. Thank you so much!